# Ajax PHP MySQL Long Polling

Tags: ajax, php, long-poll

Хотелось бы сделать систему нотификаций по типу "пришло новое сообщение".

Подкиньте, пожалуйста, примеры реализации.

обязательно в примере - метод Long pollnig
связка - ajax php mysql
бд - mysql

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что ответ был дан, а пользователь не появлялся с 5 марта 2014

Comment: С чего вдруг появилась такая политика закрытия вопросов?

Answer (score 2):

Довольно простой вариант реализации клиентской и серверной части есть у DkLab: [Realplexor](http://dklab.ru/lib/dklab_realplexor/). Для работы с БД можно у него же взять класс [DbSimple](http://dklab.ru/lib/DbSimple/)

[Еще вариант](http://www.abrandao.com/2013/05/11/php-http-long-poll-server-push/), там есть ссылки и на реализацию через Websockets.

Можно воспользоваться библиотеками [socket.io](http://socket.io/#how-to-use) на клиенте в связке с [elephant.io](http://elephant.io/#usage) на сервере